maximal monotone operator in $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$
I am considering an operator
\begin{align}
A:H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)&\to H^{-1}(\Omega)\\
u&\mapsto \int_{\Omega}\nabla u\cdot\nabla v {dx}\mbox{ for all }v\in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)
\end{align}
I already showed that this operator is monotone, so my question is whether this operator is also maximal. Because if it is a maximal monotone operator, then I can have that the sum of this operator and another maximal monotone operator is also invertibel.

Which of the equivalent characterizations of maximal monotonicity gives you trouble to check it?

@daw, the definition in my mind is that there is no proper monotone extension of this operator.

Let $\tilde A$ be a monotone extension. Take  $y \in H^1_0$ and $f\in H^{-1}$ such that $(y,f)$ is in the graph of $\tilde A$. Then we get
$$
\langle Au - f, u-y \rangle \ge0 \quad \forall u\in H^1_0
$$
by  the monotonicity of the extension. Setting $u := y + tv$ with $v\in H^1_0$, $t\in \mathbb R$ implies
$$
\langle A(y+tv)- f, tv \rangle \ge0.
$$
Dividing by $t$ and letting $t \searrow 0$ implies
$$
\langle Ay- f, v \rangle \ge0,
$$
which is equivalent to $Ay=f$. And $\tilde A=A$ follows, which is the maximality of $A$.

This proves that a linear and continuous operator is maximal monotone.
